# Driver instance must comply with the W3C specification to support getting timeout values error while using ImplicitWait

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, implicitwait

I am trying to set the implicit wait using ChomeDriver and Selenium, but I am getting an error message.

The behavior is also that the timeout does not get set and defaults to 60 seconds.

```
Driver instance must comply with the W3C specification to support getting timeout values.
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteTimeouts.ExecuteGetTimeout(String timeoutType)\r\n   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteTimeouts.get_ImplicitWait()"
```

I am using Selenium.WebDriver 3.141.0

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteTimeouts.ExecuteGetTimeout(String timeoutType)\r\n at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteTimeouts.get_ImplicitWait()
```

...implies that the syntax used for inducing **ImplicitWait** was not proper.

As per the discussion in [Support W3C WebDriver Set Timeouts format](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3607) earlier the [Set Timeouts](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#dfn-set-timeouts) command expected the data format as follows:

```
{
  implicit: 59,
}
```

But as per the W3C WebDriver multiple timeout durations can be set at the same time as follows:

```
{
  implicit: 123,
  pageLoad: 234,
  script: 456,
}
```

Your code trials would have helped us to debug your issue in a better way. Perhaps you are inducing *ImplicitWait* as per the earlier format:

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = waitTime;
```

Hence you see the error.

---

### Solution

To induce *ImplicitWait* you need to follow the following format:

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
```

---

### Outro

- [Enable reading timeouts on non-spec driver instances](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/6055)
- [Driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait gives runtime error {not a number}](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/544)